# Custom UITableViewCell (IB) only shows in selected state

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I made a custom `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder (Storyboard) and imported it to my project via `#import CustomTableViewCell.h`.

Everything works fine, but the cell is only loaded in selected state.

[image]

I want the cell to be loaded in  every row by init.

P.S. The slider and text field connections work fine. I also made all of the IB Connections.

`CustomTableViewCell.m`

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

@synthesize sliderLabel, slider;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state

}

- (IBAction)getSliderValuesWithValue:(UISlider *)sender
{
sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i / 100", (int) roundf(sender.value)];
}

@end
```

`Further Code`

```
- (CustomTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Kriterium";

CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

P.S. If I add some Buttons etc. programmatically in the above method it works. But I want to design the rows in IB. There has to be a solution.

Comment: Can you post the code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath method used when populating the UITableView with rows?

Comment: Have you designed this cell in a separate nib or as a prototype within the table view in the storyboard?

Comment: As a prototype within the table view in storyboard. I could also use a nib but I wanted all of the interface to be in one file ...

Comment: Prototype is good - note that if that is the case your cell==nil block is not necessary - the tableView will create a new cell from the prototype for you in that case. If you have any important code in there, it will not be executed.

Comment: So, I do: `CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` and delete the `nil block` ... still the same problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay ... strange things happening here ... ;-) The problem was this line:

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Leaving it out did the trick. I had to add another `UILabel` to my CustomCell which I fill with text.

**CONCLUSION**

Filling the standard `UITableViewCell.textLabel.text` seems to overwrite the PrototypeCells.

... too much customization hurts. ;-)

Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Do you mean in my solution or generally? Thanks again to you jr!

Comment: I mean generally - if you use the default cell style then add subviews to it, this is probably something to look out for.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It's just because I needed a bunch of different cell styles. It's easier for me to visualize them in IB. :)

Comment: Oh, still definitely use IB - but there is a style drop down for the prototype table cell, if this "custom" then you get a blank table cell, so all the subviews are your own.

Comment: Ah, oookay. Now I've got it. Thank you! (Though I think I did this. ;) )

Comment: Worth to say that this happens only on iOS 6. On iOS 7, it works fine.

Comment: No, happens on iOS 8 XCode 6 also.  Curse you Cocoa.

Comment: Is this an Apple bug?

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting you to not go for IB. Just define those controls as property and in your init method- initWithStyle(CustomTableViewCell.m file) initialize UISlider with its default property:

```
UISlider *tempSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
tempSlider.selected = NO;
//define other properties as well
self.slider = tempSlider;
[self addSubview:self.slider];
[tempSlider release];
```

Besides you can also set cell selection style to none.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: Thank you. But it basically has to work like [this (click)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1). Everybody uses this line which changes nothing on my problem:  `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];`