# Why is my ImageView only visible when the cell is highlighted?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have a custom Cell for my TableView, with an ImageView on it.

[image]

Why is the ImageView only visible when the cell is highlighted?

[image]

The cells are created thusly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    Site *site = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:site.description];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @amar To what? Why would this help? Currently the background of the image is transparent.

Comment: and the image contains the text chest?

Comment: @amar No, of course not that text is added to the cell in code.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but, the only difference I see is the presence of text. Edit: Oh wait. You mean the camera icon is supposed to appear on all cells?

Comment: @Max the first screenshot is Interface Builder. The second is the app actually running in the VM, with a row highlighted to show the odd behaviour.

Comment: Can we see the code where you are attaching the subview?

Comment: How did you set up the cell in IB?

Comment: @BoltClock I dragged a new Cell object to the empty TableView, gave it the correct identifier, then added the imageView. That's about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: [Custom UITableViewCell (IB) only shows in selected state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374983/custom-uitableviewcell-ib-only-shows-in-selected-state)

The quick synopsis of it "Filling the standard UITableViewCell.textLabel.text seems to overwrite the PrototypeCells". So it would appear you have to create and add a different text label.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `UIImageView` is a subview of the highlighted background view, only visible when the cell is selected?

Comment: If so, what would be the solution?

Comment: You can have you `UIImageView` subview of your cell directly, and with a z order above all the other views. this way it will be always visible.